# Get the total price of an order

Tags: mysql

I need to calculate the total price of an order.

I am using this setup:

**Orders**

```
order_id
--------
1
2
3
```

**Picklists**

```
picklist_id order_id
----------- --------
1           1
2           1
3           2
4           3
```

**Products**

```
product_id picklist_id name           price amount
---------- ----------- -------------- ----- ------
1          1           product A      100   1
2          1           product B      200   3
3          2           product C      300   2
4          3           product A      100   2
5          4           Product C      300   1
```

My question is, how do I calculate the total price for an order

So my outcome, ideally, would be something like this:

```
order_id total_price
-------- -----------
1        1200
2        200
3        300
```

**EDIT**:

Query so far:

```
SELECT
order_picklists.name,
FORMAT(SUM(price * amount), 2) AS total
FROM order_products
JOIN order_picklists ON order_picklists.id = order_products.picklist_id
GROUP BY order_picklists.name
```

This, however, only adds everything per picklist, but I need those combined for the order.

Comment: Try `GROUP BY order_picklists.order_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `GROUP BY` the `order_id` which will return only 1 row per order.

```
SELECT o.order_id, SUM(p.price * p.amount) AS total
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN picklists pl ON pl.order_id = o.order_id
LEFT JOIN products p ON pl.picklist_id = p.picklist_id
GROUP BY o.order_id;
```